# Why is "trace" expanded in Chrome for last 2 months?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

For a along time if I did `console.trace(123)` - the trace was collapsed. At some point Chrome released a new version, and since then it is always expanded. What can I do to make it appear collapsed?

Comment: https://crbug.com/697203 - use console.warn to print the trace or console.groupCollapsed wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These is a better workaround now. So they don't plan on fixing it.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=677929

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=697203

> Comment 11 by igar...@gmail.com, Apr 13 (5 days ago) ⚐
>
> Workaround above always outputs bold text and doesn't support css.
>   Here's a slightly better slightly better polyfil:
>
> ```
> if(window.console && console.trace) {
>     var oldTrace = console.trace;
>     console.trace = function(msg, css) {
>         msg = msg && String(msg) || 'trace';
>         if (!msg.startsWith('%c')) {
>             msg = '%c' + msg;
>             css = 'font-weight: normal;';
>         } else {
>             css = 'font-weight: normal; ' + String(css || '');
>         }
>         console.groupCollapsed(msg, css);
>         oldTrace.apply(this);
>         console.groupEnd();
>     } }
> ```
>
> Testing it with:
>
> ```
> console.trace('testest'); console.trace('%ctestest', 'color: #F00');
> console.trace('%ctestest', 'color: #F00; font-weight: bold;');
> console.trace(new RegExp(), new RegExp());
> ```
>
> works as expected.

Comment: Huh, smart move!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=677929

The workaround I'm aware of is to use console.error instead.